# NLP Decision confidence analysis

Tags: nlp, machine-learning-model

I have text from people explaining their decision. I want to extract a confidence score of how confident they are in their decision.
I am looking for a pre-trained model. I looked up online but I found nothing. Is there a specific name for this task?